# SFCC: scheduled jobs are not running in sandbox

Tags: commerce-cloud

Noob question here.

I have created a job in Sandbox which I set up to run every 1 minute. The job never runs automatically though. I checked the docs section [here](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/index.jsp) but was not able to find any clues or how to debug the issue.

Is there any log I can check to see what's going on? Is there some sandbox limitation for executing jobs on schedule?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the job manually and is it starting then? Have you checked the error logs of your sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else having the issue. It is confirmed in Salesforce Partner Community that jobs don't start on schedule on sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can access Salesforce jobs though the Scheduled Jobs tabs in Setup.  This will show the jobs that are scheduled.

In the Apex Jobs tab in setup you can see the result of the job and how many records were processed.

Comment: This is the commerce cloud job framework, there are no Apex jobs there